# Application appears in the menu without icon and in duplicate

Tags: gnome, launcher

I have a problem with my deskop file, I suppose, for urxvt (rxvt-unicode).
When I open urxvt (from the menu with the favorite icon or for the "seach bar"), a new icon appears in the menu bar instead of add the little red dot near the rxvt icon.
The problem doesn't occur with other applications.

In the example below, I click on my terminal icon and it opens a new icon (with gears) at the bottom of the bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqBgl.png)

If I put the mouse over the terminal icon (on top), this message appears : `Rxvt Color Unicode Terminal`, when I put it over the bottom icon, this message appears: `URxvt`.

My configuration

```
cat /usr/share/applications/rxvt-unicode.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=Rxvt Color Unicode Terminal
Comment=Terminal emulator
GenericName=Terminal
Exec=urxvt
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/iterm3.png
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=True
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;



uname -a
Linux cse-port 5.11.0-22-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 00:34:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve with this configuration.
I don't know which parameter is important.

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=rxvt-unicode
X-AppInstall-Popcon=71
X-AppInstall-Section=universe

Name=Rxvt Color Unicode Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
TryExec=urxvt
Exec=urxvt
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/iterm3.png
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=Run;
Actions=New

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Rxvt Color Unicode Terminal
Exec=urxvt
OnlyShowIn=Unity

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
```